# how to join two tables with different columns datatypes

Tags: sql, oracle

Im using toad for oracle,
I have two tables the old table CUSTOMER has columns,
 and primary Key is  **custnum** ,
 its datatype is "number".

I have created a new table TRANSACTION and it has a column with name **custnum** but its datatype is "varchar2" .

**custnum** field values in *customer* table:

```
14953252
14442752
19321147
74893221
```

---

**custnum** field values in *transaction table:*

```
14953252
AR7475552
19321147
JK8932214
P887655532
WX7893534
```

My query  has an error

```
select t.custnum,t.trascnum,c.custname,c.custaddress
from  transaction t, customer c
where 
t.custnum=c.custnum(+)
```

how to join two tables with different columns datatypes ??

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i got this error  ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 0):

You can do use `LIKE`.  And `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t.custnum, t.trascnum, c.custname, c.custaddress
from customer c left join
     transaction t 
     on t.custnum like '%' || c.custnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `CAST` function to change the data type of one variable to the other.

you would want to do something like this:

```
where transcation.custnum = CAST(customer.custnum as varchar2) (+)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks as if you're looking for a full outer join:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data; you have that & don't have to type it
  3  customer (custnum, custname) as
  4    (select 14953252, 'Scott' from dual union all
  5     select 14442752, 'Mike'  from dual union all
  6     select 19321147, 'King'  from dual
  7    ),
  8  transaction (custnum, trascnum) as
  9    (select '14953252' , 25 from dual union all
 10     select 'AR7475552', 13 from dual union all
 11     select '19321147' , 82 from dual
 12    )
 13  -- query you might be interested in
 14  select c.custnum,
 15         c.custname,
 16         t.custnum,
 17         t.trascnum
 18  from customer c full outer join transaction t
 19    on c.custnum = to_number(regexp_substr(t.custnum, '\d+$'));

   CUSTNUM CUSTN CUSTNUM     TRASCNUM
---------- ----- --------- ----------
  14953252 Scott 14953252          25
                 AR7475552         13
  19321147 King  19321147          82
  14442752 Mike

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the database to compare the two values, either `customer.cnum` has to be converted to a string, or `transaction.custnum` has to be converted to a number. Probably the error you got was

> ORA-01722: invalid number

as the database tried to treat `AR7475552` as a number.

Converting a number to a string is easier:

```
select c.custnum
     , c.custname
     , t.custnum
     , t.trascnum
from   transaction t
       left join customer c
            on to_char(c.custnum) = t.custnum;
```

but there are ways to treat a string as a number, such as this (requires Oracle 12.2 or later):

```
select c.custnum
     , c.custname
     , t.custnum
     , t.trascnum
from   transaction t
       left join customer c
            on c.custnum = to_number(t.custnum default 0 on conversion error);
```

(I found that using `default null on conversion error` in a join crashes the session, even though it is valid in a query. If it's possible for `c.custnum` to contain `0` then you could use a more obscure value such as `-1e-9`.)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
select  t.custnum,c.salary
from transactions t left outer join customer c on t.custnum=to_char(c.custnum);
```

@Littlefoot 
@Mureinik